# JQuery keydown event is only triggered once unless anything else happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show a font awesome '?' after every element that has the ".info" class when the user is holding down the "alt" key. It appears to be working but when i release "Alt" and try to press it again nothing happens. But when i click the document it works again. See code sample:

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var keyDown = false;
        $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
        console.log(keyDown);
        if (e.key == "Alt") {
            if (!keyDown) {
                $('.info').each(function () {
                    $(this).after("<a style=\"color:black;postion:absolute;\"><i class=\"fas fa-info-circle\"></i></a>");
                });
            }
            keyDown = true;
        }
        });
        $(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
        if (e.key == "Alt") {  
            console.log("alt released");
            $('.info').each(function () {
                $(".fa-info-circle").remove();
            });
            keyDown = false;
        }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="info">Test</p>
```

EDIT: When using another key (i tested "i") it seems to work fine so i think it might be a Chrome issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has a number of keyboard shortcuts that use alt - for instance alt + home takes you to your home page.

you can see all the shortcuts here:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en-GB

if you want to override Chrome's behaviour (which I do not recommend), you could add `e.preventDefault()` to your keydown function.

Comment: Yeah i thought Chrome's default behaviour was the problem.